# Best way to restrict FTP access to a single directory?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, sftp, file-permissions

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04, and I'd like to give someone SFTP access to a single directory, but prevent them from seeing anything else on the system. What's the best way to pull this off?

I considered removing "everyone" permissions from everything on the system, but that seems like a really blunt tool for this problem (and one that'll cause other issues) - I'm hoping there's a better option here.

**Edit**: I appreciate the answers! (And I learned a bunch reading/researching through them). I ended up finding and using this guide from Linode as it spelled all the steps: http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way use ftps and chroot(vsftpd) or web-dav with ssl(Apache2,nginx).

Generate a Certificate :

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024  -keyout /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem   -out /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
```

Edit config:

```
 ssl_enable=YES
 rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
 chroot_local_user=YES
```

Comment: That is FTPs not SFTP as OP asked.

Comment: @Hrvoje Easy and reliable install ftps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want SFTP  which is subsystem of SSH check out this guide
[here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590)

If you want FTP with SSL layer than ooshro suggestion is fine.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu you can use [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) fairly easily

```
sudo apt-get install scponly
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow scponly
```

Once it's installed and configured you can use the supplied script to create the user accounts and jails.

```
cd /usr/share/doc/scponly/setup_chroot
sudo gunzip setup_chroot.sh.gz
sudo chmod +x setup_chroot.sh
sudo ./setup_chroot.sh
```

Follow the onscreen prompts to configure the user.